# Python Function sum even values from a dictionary

Tags: python, sum

I am trying to write a function that receives a dictionary similar to this:

```
A = {'one':1,'two':2,'three':3,'four':4}
```

and if it is even it will sum the value, if it is odd or not numeric it will skip it.
This is my current work:

```
def sumEven(entry):
    
    count1=0
    
    for i in entry:
        a=int(entry[i])
        if(a % 2 == 0):
            count1 + i
    return
```

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I can't figure out where the `str` value is coming from.

Comment: In your code ``i`` is the key from the dictionary, and ``a`` is the value

I think you want ``count1 += a``

Answer (score 1):

You can also perform sum using python built-in `sum`.

```
sum(value for value in A.values() if value % 2 == 0)
```

**Note:** this will not work if the dictionary values are not integers

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
            count1 + i
```

To:

```
            count1 += a
```

Explanation:

```
def sumEven(entry):
    
    count1 = 0 # 0 is an integer
    for i in entry: # For i in entry is the as for every key in entry, where the keys are strings
        a = int(entry[i])
        if (a % 2 == 0):
            count1 + i # So here, you are adding a string to an integer
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should be :

```
def sumEven(entry):
    count1=0

    for key, value in entry.items():
       if(value % 2 == 0):
           count1 += value
    return count1
```

Note that :

- I used `entry.items()` to extract both the key and the value at the same time; your code just extracted the keys, and you needed a separate line to extract the value.
- You need to use `+=` when adding the value to `count1` - using `+` as you did will not store the calculated value
- I deliberately used readable variables (rather than `i` and `a`) - it is a good habit to get into
- You need to return the value you calculate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def sumEven(entry):
    count1=0
    for i in entry.values():
        a = i
        if a % 2 == 0:
            count1 += a
    return count1
```